# Replication from slave broken after table rename/swap

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds

We run a RDS MySQL master-slave replication setup and quite regularly add another replica (replicating from the slave) for maintenance, testing, analytics, etc.

However, I currently cannot create a new instance that replicates from the slave. When it starts replicating, error 1032 occurs:

```
Could not execute Update_rows event on table x.y; Can't find record in 'y', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin-changelog.083465, end_log_pos 260523
```

When I create a new instance that replicates from the master, everything works as usual.

During recent maintenance we created a new table `y_temp`, filled it with a subset of rows from `y`, and then renamed `y` to `y_old` and `y_temp` to `y`. It seems very likely that this has caused the state we're seeing, but I don't understand how. During the maintenance, slave was replicating from master as usual and it now has the same rows in `y` as master.

I have not been able to find any reports that match our situation. I would prefer to have new instances replicate from slave instead of master. Should we recreate the slave instance?

This is RDS MySQL 5.6.35 and I use the RDS console to add the read replica.

Comment: Questions :  Q1) When you made `y_temp`, did you use `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` ? Q2) Did you use `RENAME TABLE y TO y_old; ` or `ALTER TABLE y RENAME y_old;` ? Q3) Did you execute the rename command as one command (`RENAME TABLE  y TO y_old,y_temp TO y;`) or as two commands (`RENAME TABLE y_old TO y_old; RENAME TABLE y_temp TO y;`) ?

Comment: Possible workaround: create a manual snapshot of the slave.  After that is finished, wait about 10 minutes, then create a new replica from the slave.  You won't be using that snapshot for anything, so you can delete it later, but it's a way (theoretically) to convince RDS to create the new replica from a later baseline.  Would the table in question happen to be a MyISAM table?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA It was a regular `CREATE TABLE`. We used `RENAME TABLE y TO y_old;` and then `RENAME TABLE y_temp TO y;`. No other operations were sent to the database during that time (or should have been), application was in maintenance mode.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I also thought of that later yesterday and I'll try that. The table is InnoDB.

Comment: Creating a manual snapshot of the slave and trying again gave the same error.

Comment: Were USE statement involved?

Comment: @RickJames No, at least not explicitely. The table create and inserts were done from a small Ruby script using the mysql2 gem (which uses libmysql's connect function) and the rename statements directly from a mysql console which was opened with the database name in the mysql config file.

Comment: We have since also seen that while creating a new replica directly on master works (as mentioned above), we can then not create additional replicas replicating from that new replica. Replication error is the same as when replicating from one of the existing replicas.